# component above of my webview doesnt appear in react-native

Tags: react-native, webview

I want render  text and webview, but when i go to the navigation for the first time, the component above of the webview not rendered.. If i go to other page and back again to the page that have webview, the component above my webview rendered... what's  wrong eith that

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        {
          event.group &&
            <Image style={styles.image_thumb}
              source={{uri: event.group.key_photo.highres_link || 'https://www.unesale.com/ProductImages/Large/notfound.png'}}
            />
        }
        {
          event.name
          && 
            <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{event.name}</Text>
        }
        <Text style={{flex: 1}}>Detail</Text>
        {
          (event.description && event.group && event.name)
            ?  
              <MyWebView
                source={{html: event.description}}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
              />
            : 
              event.visibility !== 'public'
              ?
                <Text>Detail only visible to members</Text>
              :
                <Text>No description  yet</Text>
        }
</ScrollView>
```

this is the result when it load first time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls9nO.png)

and when i got to other page and back again it's rendered
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2mkW.png)